# JPA, How to update foreign key in JPA using eclipselink

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces

I have the following scenario.

### Tables

### Project

ProjectID             ProjectName        ClientId

```
 1              P1           1
 2              P2           2
 3              P3           5
 4              P4           1
 5              P5           3
 6              P6           2
 7              P7           4
 8              P8           4
 9              P9           5
 10             P10          3
```

### Client

ClientId         ClientName

```
1                CA
2                CB
3                CC
4                CD
5                CE
```

Entity Classes for both the tables are auto generate and are not modified.

The problem is that, for projectId 8 in Project Table, I want to change clientId from 4 to 5. How do I do that using JPA and JSF?

I have huge number of clinets and cannot show in dropdown list.

The Primefaces autocomplete is one solution, but I am unable to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let the user query for the client, or enter the id.

In JPA you can do a find() for the Client with the id.

Comment: But there are thousands of clients. How can one remember ids of all the clients?